# AVPlayer cannot play mp3-format file loaded by AVURLAsset with option AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey set to true on iOS 14

Tags: ios, avplayer, ios14

While testing my app on iOS 14, I found some mp3-format files not working properly. There's no error from start to end, but sounds only heard in the very beginning and muted in the following seconds.

Here are sample codes to reproduce.

```objectivec
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

BOOL preferPreciseDuration = YES;
NSDictionary *options = @{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: @(preferPreciseDuration)};
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:options];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];
```

I have looked into it for some time and found:

1. This problem only occurs on iOS 14+.
2. If I omit `AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey` option, everything works fine.
3. It seems to be server-related, I have tested two URLs hosting exact same file, but [sample1 works](https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/mp3/sample1.mp3) while [sample1 doesn't](https://pzpfkoey8.lightyy.com/sample1.mp3).
4. On the same server, [file1 works](https://pzpfkoey8.lightyy.com/5c8994da1484642590.mp3) while [file2 doesn't](https://pzpfkoey8.lightyy.com/5c8971b5b0c2c1474.mp3).

Answer (score -1):

I have recently implement audio features in my application it's working in **iOS 14+** too.

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?


let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "zapsplat_emergency_nuclear_power_station_meltdown_alarm_42849", withExtension: "mp3")!

do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()

} catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.description)
}
```

Comment: `AVAudioPlayer` is not suitable for playing audio from a network stream.

Comment: You want to do streaming? Can you provide audio url?

Comment: To play with `AVAudioPlayer`, the whole file have to be downloaded before player can start to play. With `AVPlayer` and `AVURLAsset`, player can start to play after loading part of file.